# WPF touchscreen plug when app is running

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, usb, touchscreen

I have an issue with my WPF app when I plug the touchscreen's USB cable when the app is already running.

The problem is that the app becomes unresponsive to mouse clicks.

I use Windows 7 and .NET 4.7 (it was the same 4, 4.5, 4.6.2).

Here is a small sample to reproduce the problem (it is just a combobox in a window):

```
<Window x:Class="TouchScreenBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="700">
        <ComboBox Height="40" Width="200">
            <ComboBoxItem>Test1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Test2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Test3</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TouchScreenBug
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how to repeat the touchscreen bug:

1. Unplug your TouchScreen's USB
2. Run the app
3. Move or let the window on the TouchScreen
4. Place your mouse pointer over the window content
5. Plug your TouchScreen's USB
6. Wait like 3 to 5 seconds for it to be detected by Windows
7. Touch the combobox to open it
8. The app is now bugged:

   - You may see that the combobox does not stay open when you open it by touch
   - The window cannot be interacted with the mouse (the combobox does not react and the window can not be closed with the mouse)
   - To make it work again, I have to focus another window

I have no problem if the touchscreen's USB is plugged before running the app.

Is there something I need to do to handle the hot plug of a touchscreen while app is running?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.